# "Difficulties with contacting" or "Difficulties contacting"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm uncertain about the headline below according to its grammar. Do you consider the headline grammatically correct? And do you prefer the headline including the "with" (inside the brackets) or excluding the "with"? Thank you very much beforehand!

"Complaints regarding difficulties (with) contacting Hurrah Airlines"

Comment: "...difficulties in contacting..."

Comment: *I'm having difficulty contacting the Hurrah airlines* is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficulties%20contacting%2C%20difficulties%20with%20contacting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficulties%20contacting%3B%2Cc0), "difficulties contacting" is much more prevalent in literature, at least; the other does not even register. This is true for several other such cases. If you look [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficulties%20identifying%2Cdifficulties%20with%20identifying&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficulties%20identifying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifficulties%20with%20identifying%3B%2Cc0), "difficulties identifying" has much greater usage than "difficulties with identifying", and [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=difficulties%20learning%2Cdifficulties%20with%20learning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifficulties%20learning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifficulties%20with%20learning%3B%2Cc0) you can see that "difficulties learning" is more common than "difficulties with learning". Many other such permutations yield similar results.

*With* is a preposition that can mean "accompanied by" or "possessing" (according to Google). In this statement, while not necessarily incorrect, *with* is a useless modifier. Does it make more sense to say "difficulties contacting" or "difficulties accompanying the act of contacting"? Clearly the first.

Both are accurate; without "with" is preferable; it's your choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ambitious answer! Such an advanced and brilliant technique using Ngrams! I've never even seen it before! I'll guess I'll write it without the "with" instead. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!